# Bash: No return value when calling a function

Tags: bash

I'm new to stackoverflow and bash scripting, so go easy on me! I've been struggling with a bash script I've been writing: when I try to call a function 'main' from my script like so:

```
variable=$("main -t $path/$i")
```

I get the error "main -t ./folder: No such file or directory"; any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Thanks Jkbkot, I'm now calling it like this:

```
variable=$(main -t "$path/$i")
```

The original error is sorted but something is still up: 'variable' seemingly isn't being assigned the value echoed in the function, though calling the function manually prints the correct value. Why might this happen?

EDIT: It seems I'm calling and echoing correctly, but when calling 'main' it seems to behave differently when called recursively to the initial call. For example it runs fine up to:

```
variable=$(main -t "$path/$i") #A line within 'main'
```

Then begins again, as expected, but this time it stops as soon as it comes across a 'break', apparently breaking out of the entire function call rather that just the 'case' it's currently in. Is there some quirk to 'break' in bash that I'm unaware of?

NOTE: Unfortunately, the script is an assignment from my university, and many of its students and teachers use this website, so publicly posting my solution would likely have negative consequences.

Comment: It would help to see your actual code, esp. the function main. For example the following works: 
`#!/bin/bash    main() {   echo "$1-bar"  }  variable=$(main foo) echo $variable`
The output is `foo-bar` as expected. Maybe your fucntion main outputs to stderr instead of stdout?

Comment: As I've added above, I can't really post the full code. How would I know which I'm outputting to? I'm just using 'echo'.

Comment: Try to run the snippet from my previous comment and see for yourself that it works as expected. You may change the last echo as `echo VARIABLE:$variable` to avoid any confusion output of which echo you see. Wrt stderr, you can try to redirect stderr to stdout: `variable=$(main -t "$path/$i" 2>&1)` If it works then your function outputs to stderr. Also, you can enable "debugging" by putting `set -x` at the beginning of your script (on a line after the hashbang).

Comment: Finally got back on this, and the above snippet worked. I had a look through with debugging on and found what appears to be the problem, which I've written above.

Comment: how exactly are you "breaking" out of the "case"? You want to say you want to exit just the current call of the function? Calling e.g. return 0 should work fine. Break is used only for jumping out of loops.

Comment: As in: case "$1" in, -t ), *CODE*, break;;.

Comment: So the whole case statement is inside a loop?

Comment: Have... I misunderstood 'break'? I thought it could be used to break out of other things, such as 'case' selections. My background is in Java (at a very basic level), where 'break' is required to stop a case statement attempting every item you list, even if it has found a matching one.

Comment: Yes, it seems so and yes it is different than in Java. Just type `help case` on the command line and you'll see that there is no break in the syntax. And `help break` which states: `Exit a FOR, WHILE or UNTIL loop.  If N is specified, break N enclosing
    loops.`

Comment: Ah, I'll adjust my use of 'break' accordingly and get back to you.

Comment: All fixed, thanks friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to call it without the quotes:

```
variable=$(main -t $path/$i)
```

and as @janos says, you might need the quotes around the variables in case they might contain spaces, etc.:

```
variable=$(main -t "$path/$i")
```

Comment: careful, he might very well need the quotes inside: `variable=$(main -t "$path/$i")`

Comment: true, he might need the quotes around the variables only

Comment: Thanks both of you, but I've hit a different problem, detailed above.